# Can I get the key from SharedPreferences if a know the associated value?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, key-value

Is it possible to get the "key" value from a SharedPreferences file if I know the "value" value it is paired with?

Let's say I've gone into the SharedPreferences file and, through a user action, have got the value "London, UK".

Now I want to get the KEY associated with the value "London, UK" and then use that for my next step, is this possible?

The code I use at the moment to getAll data from the SharedPerferences, sort it by value, populate an AlertDialog with this data, deal with a user choosing an option from the AlertDialog and then returning the value of that choice. I now need the KEY that's paired with the value.

```
public void openServerDialog() {


        final SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
        TreeMap<String, ?> keys = new TreeMap<String, Object>(myPrefs.getAll());
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
            Log.i("map values", entry.getKey());
            //some code
        }


      List<Pair<Object, String>> sortedByValue = new LinkedList<Pair<Object,String>>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
            Pair<Object, String> e = new Pair<Object, String>(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
            sortedByValue.add(e);
        }

     // Pair doesn't have a comparator, so you're going to need to write one.
        Collections.sort(sortedByValue, new Comparator<Pair<Object, String>>() {
            public int compare(Pair<Object, String> lhs, Pair<Object, String> rhs) {

                String sls = String.valueOf(lhs.first);
                String srs = String.valueOf(rhs.first);
                int res = sls.compareTo(srs);
                // Sort on value first, key second
                return res == 0 ? lhs.second.compareTo(rhs.second) : res;
            }
        });

        for (Pair<Object, String> pair : sortedByValue) {
            Log.i("map values", pair.first + "/" + pair.second);
        }


      Collection<?> stringArrayList = keys.values();
      final CharSequence[] prefsCharSequence = stringArrayList.toArray(new CharSequence[stringArrayList.size()]);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)   
        .setTitle(R.string.server_title)
        .setItems(prefsCharSequence, 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {

                setServer(prefsCharSequence[i]);   

            }
        })
        .show();
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `SharedPreferences.getAll` method.

```
String findKey(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String value) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: sharedPreferences.getAll().entrySet()) {
        if (value.equals(entry.getValue())) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null; // not found
}
```

You should note that while keys are guaranteed to be unique in SharedPreferences, there's no guarantee that the values will be unique. As such, this function will only return the key for the first matching value.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am quite new to Android and am getting some errors when placing this in my code. Should I be replacing any of your code with data from my project?

Comment: You need to import the SharedPreferences class and the Map class.

Comment: I have both these imported already. I successfully use a tree map to get the value, now I have the value I need the key for that value. Your code looks like exactly what I need just, due to my inexperience I'm not sure how to execute. I'll edit my initial post with more data

Comment: error `foreach not applicable to type 'java.util.Map<java.lang.String,capture<?»'` occured. you should add `.entrySet()` after `sharedPreferences.getAll()` to solve this error. so it should be `for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry: sharedPreferences.getAll().entrySet()){...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), 0);

Iterator iter = prefs.getAll().entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)iter.next();
       // Check the value here
    }
```

You can iterate over that map and look for the value you want.

Comment: how would I then get the key from the value I have? My code in the opening questions gets me the value, but I need the key for that value.

Comment: I get a "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" error when copying that code, any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, that god rid of most of the errors. I now get a SynergyApplication can't be resolved and neither can context. I assume I have to replace these with something from my project?

Comment: Yeah, well, you should just replace it with Context (applicationContext, Activity)