# Is it possible to get the "key" value from a SharedPreferences file if I know the value it is paired with?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, key-value, android-alertdialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get the key from SharedPreferences if a know the associated value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713321/can-i-get-the-key-from-sharedpreferences-if-a-know-the-associated-value)

The code below I use to populate an AlertDialog from a SharedPreferences file and sort it alphabetically by value.

When the user clicks an option in the AlertDialog list it launches

```
 setServer(prefsCharSequence[i]);
```

prefsCharSequence[i] returns the value for the option chosen.

**I want to use the "key" for that value**. How do I go about getting this given my current code? now I know the value I was hoping it would be a simple "prefsCharSequence[i].getKey()" or something similar.

```
public void openServerDialog() {


        final SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
        TreeMap<String, ?> keys = new TreeMap<String, Object>(myPrefs.getAll());
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
            Log.i("map values", entry.getKey());
            //some code
        }


      List<Pair<Object, String>> sortedByValue = new LinkedList<Pair<Object,String>>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
            Pair<Object, String> e = new Pair<Object, String>(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
            sortedByValue.add(e);
        }

     // Pair doesn't have a comparator, so you're going to need to write one.
        Collections.sort(sortedByValue, new Comparator<Pair<Object, String>>() {
            public int compare(Pair<Object, String> lhs, Pair<Object, String> rhs) {

                String sls = String.valueOf(lhs.first);
                String srs = String.valueOf(rhs.first);
                int res = sls.compareTo(srs);
                // Sort on value first, key second
                return res == 0 ? lhs.second.compareTo(rhs.second) : res;
            }
        });

        for (Pair<Object, String> pair : sortedByValue) {
            Log.i("map values", pair.first + "/" + pair.second);
        }


      Collection<?> stringArrayList = keys.values();
      final CharSequence[] prefsCharSequence = stringArrayList.toArray(new CharSequence[stringArrayList.size()]);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)   
        .setTitle(R.string.server_title)
        .setItems(prefsCharSequence, 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {

                setServer(prefsCharSequence[i]);   

            }
        })
        .show();
    }
```

I'm trying to iterate over and grab the key for the value I have, so far I have this but don't know where to go next:

```
CharSequence server = i;
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Map<String, ?> items = myPrefs.getAll();
        for(String s : items.keySet()){


        }
```

i equals the value for the key I want, is this heading in the right direction?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You can just iterate over your map of preferences, and return the key when the value matches. Is there something more to this question than that?

Comment: Hi @Tim, I'm new to Android programming and don't understand your "iterate over" remark. You're right, that is what I want to do, but don't know how to fit it into my code of where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim suggested, you can refer to [getAll()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29) function of `SharedPreferences` class.

This will return you `Map<String,?>` object, you can use `keySet()` function of `Map` class for getting the keySet and for iterating use a `foreach` loop of Java.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the information. Please check my opening post edit (at the bottom) to see if I'm on the right lines?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, prefsCharSequence is an array of the values from your SharedPreferences object. If that is the case, why not just keep an array of keys from the prefs? The value would be prefsCharSequence[i], and the key would be something like prefsCharSequenceKeys[i].

Comment: see my comment above on the initial question